# Assume $f'$ is continuous on$[0,2]$, Prove $\max_{x\in[0,2]} |f(x)|\le|\frac{1}{2}\int_0^2f(x)\text dx|+\int_0^2|f'(x) |\text dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Assume $f'$ is continuous on$[0,2]$. Prove
$$\max_{x\in[0,2]} |f(x)|\le \left|\frac{1}{2}\int_0^2f(x)\text dx \right|+\int_0^2|f'(x) |\text dx$$
I think it's about Taylor expansion. But really don't know how to do these dirty tricks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might know that, with $f$ continuous on $[0,2]$, we can find $c$ and $x_0$ in $[0,2]$ such as :

$$ \frac{1}{2-0} \int_0^2 f(t)\text{dt} = f(c) \quad \text{and} \quad \underset{x \in [0,2]}{\max} |f(x)| = |f(x_0)|$$

(see Mean Value Theorem for integrals). Then, we can write :

$$ \left| \int_c^{x_0} f'(t) \text{dt} \right | = |f(x_0) - f(c)| $$

Using the triangle inequality for integrals and real numbers, we have :

$$  |f(x_0)| - |f(c)|\leqslant |f(x_0) - f(c)| =  \left| \int_c^{x_0} f'(t) \text{dt} \right | \leqslant \int_c^{x_0} |f'(t)| dt \leqslant \int_0^{2} |f'(t)| \text{dt} $$

if $c \leqslant x_0$ (we can do the same if $x_0 \leqslant c$). Which finally leads to :

$$  |f(x_0)| = \underset{x \in [0,2]}{\max} |f(x)| \leqslant \left | \frac{1}{2} \int_0^2 f(t)\text{dt}\right|  +  \int_0^{2} |f'(t)| \text{dt}$$

Comment: Good answer, but there's few errors. $|f(x_0)-f(x)| = |\int_c^{x_0} f'(t)dt|$. Now if $c\leq x_0$, we have $|\int_c^{x_0} f'(t)dt|\leq \int_c^{x_0} |f'(t)|dt$, $|\int_c^{x_0} f'(t)dt|\leq \int_{x_0}^c |f'(t)|dt$ otherwise.

Comment: Thanks, I edited.